# RecyclerView shift items

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a calendar, in which the days are in a RecyclerView.
I want to show the first day of the month on the column of the day of the week it starts on.
Is there a way to shift the items so that the first item starts on the right column?
Attached picture explains what I need.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't care about the position in the column based on the day of the week.

One way is to have one Date instance for each day. To show one year in the above form you need to have a gridview 7x52. First cell in the gridview will have the first day of the year. The second day will go to the second position etc.. You can also extract from that the day of the month to produce the result you want.

You will need headers for that. Check this http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

One way to create days for the adapter of your grid:

```
For every day out of the 365 {
Calendar newDay = Calendar.getInstance();
newDay.set(Year, 2016);
newDay.set(Calendar.Day_Of_Year, 0<i<365);
Arraylist adaptersData.add(newDay);
{
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understand what you meant and that solves my problem. Could you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Which part you don't understand? You said "Is there a way to shift the items so that the first item starts on the right column?" I am saying you don't need to worry about that. If you create a calendar for a year, put the days on the 7days X 52weeks gridview according to the day of the year value of the Date instance.

Comment: 1. I want to show it in a format of a month, not a year. 2. Even if I show it in a year, how would I put the first items in the right day, if, for instance, the first day of the year starts on Wednesday? 3. How will headers help me in this?

Comment: You want to be able to scroll right? To navigate between months. So let's say you want to show 2016. In your gridview which has 365 cells, the first cell (grid[0]) will take a Date which will have the 0+1 day of the year(something like thisCalendar.getInstance().set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0)). Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: But how does that solve that I want to show the date in the right day of the week?

Comment: let's say the first day of the year is friday. Friday as day of the week is 6. So in the grid the first day of the year will go in the first row, column 6. You can fill the rest of the days with a loop.

Comment: That's not my problem. The problem is how to put the first day in column 6, using a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager, not a GridLayout?

Comment: Check my post again. I never mentioned GridLayout. Check the link I have posted.

Comment: I know you didn't. Except that I don't understand how to place an item in a certain column with a Recyclerview, and what does it have to do with Headers?

Comment: 1. The link with the headers is a very good example to see some of the features of the gridLayoutManager and how to use them. 2. So your problem is that you don't know how the GridlayoutManager works? You need to re read the tutorials. 3. Check also this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/ . The adapter uses a list of items, right? Use my pseudo-code to fill the array and pass it to the adapter. I can't do the job for you.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I still don't understand how to move items in the recyclerview so that they will be under their correct day of the week column, and the items before (say Sunday till Tuesday) will be blank?